# How to make Dask lazy like PySpark for operations like .head(20)?

Tags: python, dask

In **PySpark**, whenever I line up a bunch of complex operations on a very large dataframe `df` and then type:

```
df.show(20)
```

Spark will only do what is necessary (on a partial dataset) to quickly return 20 records for display. It doesn't carry out the operations on all the rows of the dataframe `df` unless I force it to do so with `.collect()`.

On the other hand, in **Dask**, when I do the same thing:

```
df.head(20)
```

Dask will actually carry out the operations on the entire dataframe (and it churns for a long time) and then returns the top 20 records.

The Dask approach makes it unwieldy for iterating ideas quickly on very large datasets. Is there a way to make Dask more responsive by intelligently doing just enough to return a subset of records for inspection?

Answer (score 2):

The following command

```
df.head(20)
```

only takes data from the first partition of your dataframe, assuming that it has at least 20 rows. Note that the *whole* of the first partition will be required.
Exactly what work is required to make this happen depend on how `df` is defined, for instance: it might depend on a lot of the input data for some complex groupby/shuffle operation and how big a partition size you are working with.

Generally speaking, (py)Spark is heavily optimised for SQL-like workflows and is able to do high-level SQL planning to get performance, whereas the optimisations in Dask tend to be lower-level, sacrificing some performance in certain circumstances for flexibility (you can achieve complex workflows in Dask that are not possible or very hard with Spark).

Having said all that, more details on what you are finding slow may allow a response with specific suggestions on improving performance.

Comment: Dask isn't slow per se (in fact it's faster than Spark), but if I were say to do a column calculation (say, lambda x: x * 2) and output 20 rows for inspection, Spark would only apply that function to 20 rows, whereas it seems like Dask would apply it to the entire df, and then show 20 rows. Would this be a correct characterization?

Comment: No, you would tend to get the operation applied to the whole of the first partition, so it depends on how the data is partitioned.

Comment: I think that may be what is happening. I’m working on a single large parquet file (so the first partition is also the entire data frame). Spark returns instantaneously and Dask takes a minute or so to return. Perhaps with dask I have to work with smaller partitions of the same data....

Comment: Yeah, the python parquet drivers don't have the ability to read only a few rows of a partition (fastparquet could in principle, but I'd be the one to do it, and I have no such plans; pyarrow perhaps could be persuaded with minor changes, I'm not sure)